# Using global variables for testing in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I've recently been testing a web application developed in Node.js. We're using Mocha, Sinon, Supertest and Proxyquire.

Before  I entered the project, another guy developed the test suite for the web application.

In the test folder, there is a Javascript file named commons.js

```
commons.js

global.sinon = require('sinon');
global.expect = require('chai').expect;
global.supertest = require('supertest');
global.request = supertest('http://localhost:8051');
global.express = require('express');
global.app = express();
global.proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
```

These variables are used in all the tests. They're used for testing controllers and routers.

I was wondering if this is a good practice to follow. On the one hand, I know that we should avoid using global variables in our applications, but I don't know if this also applies for testing. On the other hand, I feel like repeating those variables at beginning of each test file is somehow violating the DRY principle

What should I do? Should I refactor all tests or just leave them as they are now?

Comment: This fits squarely within the realm of preferences. I prefer not to do what you describe there, but Mocha itself put `describe`, `it`, etc. in the global space (and some people reject Mocha *because of this*). What you should do really depends on the nature of your project, the development constraints you have, your plans for the future of the project, etc. While my projects don't usually send a bunch of stuff into the global space in my test suites, I've contributed to FOSS projects that did. They are used by thousands of people every day to do productive work, and the sky has not fallen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, this does fall in the realm of preferences. Even though it is not recommended to use the global scope, as it seems glue-ish, it is not a big deal to go down that road (especially with mocha).

However, if your tests are spread throughout several files and there is a need to run a single test file, there is a small pitfall you can run into.

**Structure:**

```
├── package.json
├── test.js
├── common.js
├── tests
    ├── test-1.js
    ├── test-2.js
    └── test-3.js
```

**Case: Running single (independent tests)**

**Example:** Lets say running ALL tests takes ~30 sec, you are writing the last test file in your testing suite which does independent testing. Should run single test.

**The code:**

**package.json**

```
...
"scripts": {
  "mocha --reporter spec test.js"
},
...
```

**common.js - Same as above**

```
global.sinon = require('sinon');
global.expect = require('chai').expect;
global.supertest = require('supertest');
global.request = supertest('http://localhost:8051');
global.express = require('express');
global.app = express();
global.proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
```

**test.js**

```
'use strict';

require('./common.js');

function runTest(testDesciption, file) {
  describe(testDesciption, function () {
    require('./tests/' + file);
  });
}

describe('My tests', function () {
    runTest('Running tests-1', 'test-1.js');
    runTest('Running tests-2', 'test-2.js');
    runTest('Running tests-3', 'test-3.js');
});
```

**tests/test-n.js**

```
it("Should not throw error", function () {
    console.log(`Sinon: ${!!sinon}, Expect: ${!!expect}, Supertest ${!!supertest}, Proxyquire: ${!!proxyquire}`)
    expect(!!sinon).to.equal(true);
    expect(!!supertest).to.equal(true);
    expect(!!proxyquire).to.equal(true);
})
```

**The pitafall:** 
    `mocha --reporter spec tests/test-n.js`

Running a single test file will result in a ReferenceError since the dependencies are not included in the global scope.

**The workaround**:

- Bad: `require('../common.js')` in every test file
- Good: Using `mocha --grep <describe_pattern>` as CLI **OR** `describe.only` from the code.

[Mocha usage](https://mochajs.org/#usage)

[Mocha exclusive tests](https://mochajs.org/#exclusive-tests)

In this way, you avoid ReferenceError, since the test will run from the root test file, load common.js, skip all tests except the exclusive test which is provided.

### A case for dependencies declaration inside each test file

I would argue that declaring dependencies inside each file is good practice.

**1.** Demystify `require()`

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

Requiring modules does not slow you down, after the fist require.

**2.**. Each file is a compact logical unit, that contains everything you need to run as a standalone test.

**3.**: Some test files require a subset of packages you are using (not all), keeping it clean.

---

**TL;DR:** All in all, there is no need to change up things if it works for you. Hope this info will provide some more context for you in your decision making.